# Wait For Response returns postData as NONE in robot-browser

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation, playwright

I am using robot-browser for UI automation and in one case I am using `Wait For Response` keyword for a `GET` call like this:

`Wait For Response     response => response.url().endsWith('students') && response.request().method() === 'GET'`

and it returns an error as

`the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType`

I can see the api is GET call is returning the result correctly, but after some debugging I have found out that robot-browser is converting `postData` from request to JSON. But as this is a GET call, it does not have any postData and so the above error is returned.

Anyone has faced this before and how to solve this? any help is appreciable.